# What's the best way to translate a phrase containing the expression "now that"?

Tags: word-choice

Is there an expression in Esperanto which is similar to the English "now that"? For example:

> Now that I have stopped smoking I cough much less often.

Does it work to translate it word-for-word like this:

> Nun ke mi ĉesis fumi mi tusas multe malpli ofte.

Or is it better to use a construct like this:

> Ĉesinte fumi, mi tusas multe malpli ofte.

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are correct. "Now that" can usually be translated with *Nun ĉar* (or *ke* or sometimes *kiam*).

> Nun ĉar mi ĉesis fumi, mi tusas multe malpli ofte.
>
> Nun ĉar vi atentas min, mi povas daŭrigi la lecionon.
>
> Nun ĉar vi mencias, mi ja estas malsata.

Your second method is neater, but this one is more generally applicable.

Comment: This seems like a good option and I think it directly contains the meaning without needing an idiom. I wonder if it would be better to move the "nun" into the second half, like "ĉar mi ĉesis fumi mi nun tusas multe malpli". Thanks! You're right, the "inte" idea doesn't work for phrases like "now that my husband stopped smoking, I cough less".

Answer (score 0):

The PMEG article on *nun* includes examples with both *nun ke* and *nun kiam*.

http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/nun.html

You could also use a participle, as you suggested.